# How to avoid generating Ethereum DAG for tests?

Tags: java, docker, integration-testing, ethereum, geth

I'm having integration tests with private Ethereum network running in Docker. Generating of DAG takes few minutes and at least 2 Gb (1Gb for epoch 0 and 1).  I've set difficulty in custom genesis block 0x1 and it's still to much.

I can run tests on local machine and mount volume to `/root/.ethash` to reuse DAG between tests. But it prevents me from running tests on Bitbucket because of time and storage limitations.

Is there any way to avoid generating DAG for tests?

Comment: Would PoA consensus be an option?

Comment: I solved the same problem by creating a custom Docker image based on `ethereum/client-go`. It contains a layer with the folder `/root/.ethash` containing the pregenerated DAG.

Answer (score 1):

Ethash mining [needs](http://www.hashcash.org/papers/dagger.html) the DAG.

A quick workaround for private testnets is to use Clique (PoA consensus) instead.

You can configure Clique in the genesis.json like this:

```
  "config": {

    "clique": {
      "period": 5,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  }
```

The sealing will happen at regular intervals of `period` seconds. There is no other impact on the working of the network or the contracts.

The only potential downside is that Clique needs at least 2 nodes.

Comment: at least 2 _miner_ nodes?